# regex PHP find string and delete parent

Tags: php, regex

in a very big string I have to delete the [w:r][/w:r] where the substring "delete" exist.
Example -of substring I want to delete - :

```
[w:r w:rsidR="00A37EED" w:rsidRPr="00FE1BE1"][w:rPr][w:b][/w:rPr][w:t]delete[/w:t][/w:r]
```

This one is my best guess `\[w:r.*delete.*\[\/w:r\]`
I tried multiple regex expression but it's not my strong suit.

I copy-pasted the string on regex101 here's the link https://regex101.com/r/wS4bL2/1

I succeeded at finding the required pattern but I can't make it stop at the first occurence of `[/w:r]`.

PHP code -in case you are wondering- :

```
$this->tempDocumentMainPart = preg_replace('/\[w:r.*delete.*\[\/w:r\]/','',$this->tempDocumentMainPart);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.*` will overflow across the `[....]`s. One way is to use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```
\[w:r\b(?:(?!\[w:r\b).)*?delete(?:(?!\[w:r\b).)*?\[\/w:r]
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mN4sR3/1)

The `(?:(?!\[w:r\b).)*?` tempered greedy token will limit matching inside one `[w:r` (that has a word boundary on the right).

Add a DOTALL modifier `/s` (`'/PATTERN/s'`) so as to match across newlines.

Comment: It's hard to boost this regex performance by unrolling the pattern as [`'~\[w:r\b[^[]*(?:\[(?!w:r\b)[^[]*)*delete[^[]*(?:\[(?!w:r\b)[^[]*)*?\[\/w:r]~'`](https://regex101.com/r/mN4sR3/2) - the input is full of square brackets :( But still it is faster.

Comment: it seems great, let me try this on multiple examples and I'll be back with the green check

Comment: I suggest using the unrolled variant, it is faster and is thus more reliable.

Comment: yea that's what I used